# WorkspaceAPI not working in Lightning component, if component is using lightning out app

Tags: lightning, lightning-out, lightning-console, workspaceapi

as lightning components are not supported in List view button, i have used lightning out to serve the purpose, but WorkspaceAPi is not working in Lightning component as it using lightning out.
i need to navigate and switch lightning console tabs
please let us know if we have work around the for the same